# Installed ffmpeg but i'm getting a "no such file or directory" error

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg and I can run it perfectly find when using the "ffmpeg" from the command line. But I am trying to run ffmpeg from PHP and when I use the bare ffmpeg command, I get "**sh: ffmpeg: command not found**". So instead of just the bare ffmpeg command, I used the whole folder location **/home/vibe/public_html/libraries/ffmpeg/ffmpeg** but now I get the "no such file or directory" error.

Anyone know how I can solve this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adapt the configuration of your webserver... normally ffmpeg and stuff like that is installed in the same directory, for example /something/bin. So everytime you want to execute something in the shell, the OS will look into the /bin-folder. If ffmpeg is installed somewhere else (obviously it is in your case), you have to add the path to your path-variable, so the OS knows that it has to look there, too. Beside this, you should not install executables in your public_html folder!

Comment: Good point about not installing executables in my public_html, thanks for that. And thanks for the info on the path variable. So I have now moved ffmpeg to /opt/ffmpeg and run the following command "export PATH=/opt/ffmpeg/:$PATH" but I still have the same problem as before...am I doing this right? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, maybe the path is not set right, you will find here some information about that: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-set-path-variables-403964/. Output your path via ssh and type "which ffmpeg" to see, where your OS will search for it

Comment: Ahah! Right so I ran which ffmpeg in shell (logged in as root) it came up with "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg" which I guess is why ffmpeg works fine from there. When I ran which ffmpeg from PHP, I get this "which: no ffmpeg in (/bin:/usr/bin) " - how come PHP is looking for executables in a different folder than when i'm in shell?

Comment: Great, it's solved! I'm just executing it from PHP like this /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i etc.. etc.. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect that your webserver doesn't have read permission for at least one of the files or directories in that path.  The bad, shotgun solution for that would be:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/vibe/public_html
```

This would at least allow you to trivially verify that permissions are in fact your problem.

Comment: Thanks Frank for getting back. As strauberry suggested, it's not great to have executables in the public_html directory so I moved it to /opt/ffmpeg - I tried the command chmod -R 777 /opt/ffmpeg but there was no joy...anything else that could be the problem? Thank you!